# How to run functions in different QThreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, loops, qthread

How can I run loop functions in different `QThreads`? I need to run in different threads because if I don't do it, the loops break.

How to make the `on_pushTurnOn_clicked` be executed in other thread, and the loop that `pushTurnOn` must be able to be canceled by `on_pushTurnOff_clicked` even on a different thread.

`MainWindow` .h code:

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread> //I don't know how to use it
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

        void on_pushTurnOn_clicked();

        void on_pushTurnOff_clicked();

private:

QTimer *timerLoop;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`MainWindow` cpp code:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushTurnOn_clicked()
{
    timerLoop = new QTimer(this);
    timerLoop->setInterval(3000);
    timerLoop->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timerLoop, SIGNAL(timeout()), 
    SLOT(on_pushTurnOn_clicked()));

    qDebug()<<"the loop was started";
    timerLoop->start(); //start the loop
}

void MainWindow::on_pushTurnOff_clicked()
{
    qDebug()<<"the loop was stoped";
    timerLoop->stop(); //stop the loop
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't make complete sense but you can use the Qthread::run for the purpose. That's all I understand from this question

Comment: Just keep note that you are creating a new QTimer every time you are entering `on_pushTurnOn_clicked()`. That is probably not what you want with the possible memory leak?

Comment: An elegant approach would be to allocated the QTimer in the constructor and connect to a slot that does the work. Inside `on_pushTurnOn_clicked()` you start the timer once (not single shot) and inside `on_pushTurnOff_clicked()` you stop the timer like you are doing.This way you do not need to run a second thread.

Comment: @Aditya I need to create a second thread, this is 2% of the program itselfs... The true purpose is to connect in a PLC on the main thread, and do a loop check on another PLC. (2 threads for 2 different IP's).

Comment: @JoãoPedro Then I believe your best bet is to have a second class which is allocated when you click button on and is moved to a QThread. You can have the timer and work load inside that thread.

Comment: Here is a good source I used when I first had to use QThread: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start with a side note. Your memory allocation for `timerLoop` in `on_pushTurnOn_clicked()` will cause a memory leak due to absence of deallocation, even though it is a single shot timer. You are creating a new `QTimer` without destroying the previous allocated one. The better approach is to just allocate memory once in the constructor and just start the timer in `on_pushTurnOn_clicked()`.

Coming back to your question, you will have to split your class into two, one is your `mainWindow` which has the slots for `on_pushTurnOn_clicked()` and `on_pushTurnOff_clicked()`, other possible UI elements and non-intensive tasks.

The second class is a worker which contains the `QTimer` along with the actual work load. So you would essentially have something like this:

**MainWindow.cpp:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //constructor
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->worker = new Worker(); //object of WorkerClass type
    QThread *thread = new QThread();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(startOrStopTimerSignal(bool), worker, SLOT(startStopTimer(bool));
}
void MainWindow::on_pushTurnOn_clicked()
{
    if(Busy==1){
        qDebug()<<"Is busy!";
    }
    if(Busy==0){
    FuncaoLoop(RandomParameter1, RandomParameter2);
    }
//start the timer through a signal (timers need to be started in their own threads)
    emit startOrStopTimerSignal(true);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushTurnOff_clicked()
{
    emit startOrStopTimerSignal(false); //stop the timer
}
```

**WorkerClass.h/.cpp:**

```
WorkerClass::WorkerClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    timerLoop= new QTimer(this);
    connect(timerLoop, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(workLoad())); //timer connect to your actual task
}
void WorkerClass::startStopTimer(bool start)
{
    if (start)
        timerLoop->start();
    else
        timerLoop->stop();
}
WorkerClass::workLoad()
{
    //whatever task for your PLC
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!